# Data on hurricanes?

Tags: usa, api, weather, programming

As a programmer and meteorology enthusiast, I'd love to be able to get latitude/longitude of tropical storms/hurricanes (specifically in the Atlantic). Does anyone know of websites that can provide information regarding tropical activity? I looked at the NWS's API (http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/), but it doesn't seem to give such data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOAA's [Hurricane Center](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/) has [current gis](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/) as well as [archived hurricane data](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/data/)

Answer (score 4):

Wunderground has a quite extensive hurricane archive (since 1851), unfortunately they are a commercial organisation, so you'll probably have to pay for API integration with their historic data. A webpage of the data is here: 
https://www.wunderground.com/hurricane/hurrarchive.asp

You can also delve somewhat deeper into the global weather datasets, an international effort to find all the data somewhat more easily: 
http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/ibtracs/index.php

Comment: Unfortunately, wunderground is out of the question due to the commercial-ness. However, I think I should investigate the noaa ibtracs solution. Thanks!